# Define number of Firestore documents in Snapshot.data.lenght flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I my app user are going to create by TextForm Field a collection into FIrestore and this collection has some documents.
Into my StreamBuilder I have set up stream and I can get the documents but I cant retrieve the Number of the documents created by the user logged with snapshot.data.lenght which I get the error:

```
Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'lenght'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: lenght
```

The code:

```
class CollectData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CollectDataState createState() => _CollectDataState();
}

class _CollectDataState extends State<CollectData> {
  final String phone;
  final String wife;
  final String location;

  _CollectDataState({this.phone, this.wife, this.location,});

  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getDatabase() async* {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    yield* Firestore.instance
        .collection('dataCollection')
        .document(user.uid)
        .snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context,) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: getDatabase(),
      builder: (context, snapshot,) {
        if (snapshot.data != null) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 500,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.lenght,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int) {
                    return Card(
                      color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                      elevation: 15,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 60,
                        height: 60,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Card(
                              color: Color(0xfffeaf0d),
                              child: Container(
                                  height: 40,
                                  width: 40,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.contacts,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 25,
                                  )),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              snapshot.data['phone'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        } else
          return NoData();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: there seems to be typo in `'lenght`, you meant `length`, right?

Answer (score 2):

A lot of things have changed in the newest version of Flutter and Firebase.

Where you call the StreamBuilder you have to pass in the QuerySnapshot type like this:

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(...
```

And change your `itemCount` line to:

```
itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
```

That should solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

[`DocumentSnapshot`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_snapshot.dart) doesn't have any length property because, when you are doing this:

```
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getDatabase() async* {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    yield* Firestore.instance
        .collection('dataCollection')
        .document(user.uid)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

It means you are only retrieving 1 document, since each document id is unique then the above will give you only one document.

You can add here:

```
itemCount: 1
```

---

If you want a list of documents then you have to do the following:

```
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getDatabase() async* {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    yield* Firestore.instance
        .collection('dataCollection')
        .snapshots();
  }
```

and then in `itemCount`:

```
itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length
```

Comment: Yes If I add itemCount: 1; it works but it has to retrieve a list of documents, every time the user add by form field into the collection must be list 2 etc... list 3... so I thought snapshot.data.lenght works instead no

Comment: what to add to DocumentSnapshot to give a property list?

Comment: in your query you are retrieving one document, if you want a list of documents then you should use `.collection('dataCollection').snapshots();` which will return a QuerySnapshot then you can do `itemCount : snapshot.data.documents.length` or if you are using `cloud_firestore:0.14.0` then you do `itemCount:snapshot.data.docs.length`

Comment: adding this to DocumentSnapshot return: The method 'document' isn't defined for the type 'Stream'.

Comment: Did you change it to `.collection('dataCollection').snapshots();`? Also `documents` with an `s`

Comment: yes as you can see here: https://codeshare.io/a3dNAm if I change as you told it return the error even document with S

Comment: I am sorry Peter But nothing is changed maybe didnt saved? please share a new URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220141/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-tizi-dev).

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be typo in `lenght`, you meant `length`, right?
your error message clearly complaining about typo

```
Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'lenght'.
```

plz just try replacing this line `itemCount: snapshot.data.lenght,` with `itemCount: snapshot.data.length,`

Comment: `DocumentSnapshot` only returns one document thus doesn't have any `length` property.. If OP was returning a `QuerySnapshot` then use it would be a typo mistake https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_snapshot.dart

Comment: even if it returns 0, 1 or more documents, there is `length` method.  as I shared in the answer, your issue seems to be caused by a simple typo.

Comment: I'm not OP, please check the `DocumentSnapshot` class that I shared with you https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_snapshot.dart , there is no `length` nor `lenght` properties in the class, and the class doesnt have any method or property that returns a `List`

Comment: can u plz just try replacing this line `itemCount: snapshot.data.lenght,` with `itemCount: snapshot.data.length,`?  
the docs you shared are about the `snapshot` not its child `.data` which is simple `Map`

Comment: u wrote the same or ?